# S3 Direct Link for Active Storage Files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I need to set direct link of files uploaded to AWS S3 server. I am using `url_for(Model.first.image)`. But it first links to server path and then redirects to S3 Bucket path.

I have also tried the below code, but it's not working

```
Model.first.image.service_url
```

It throws error:

```
URI::InvalidURIError (bad URI(is not URI?): nil)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use image tag with following way to use direct S3 URL:

```
<%= image_tag Model.first.image.variant(resize_to_limit: [50, 50]).processed.service_url %>
```